# Stateful Child Widget not updating when parent widget updates

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Is it true that a stateful widget has to be updated/rebuild by itself and if the parent widget updates, it should also update right ?

What are the solutions for that.

I want to implement a quiz app. it has playquiz widget shows viewquiz or resultpage depending on question index which are all fetched using provider.

viewquiz has  question text and answeroptions(stateful widget). When I click answer it notifies all consumers. I can use setstate to change color but when next question comes the color stays the same if i change color to blue then it stays blue. for now the solution is to use timer for that and reset back again using setstate.

## Code

Here is my solution. If someone can help me imporve it. i feel like this is not the best way to do it.

quizmodel.dart

```
class QuizModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  var questions;

  QuizModel(this.questions);

  var qindex = 0;
  var score = 0;
  void check(ans) {
    if (ans) {
      score = score + 1;
    }

    qindex = qindex + 1;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

playquiz.dart

```
 return ChangeNotifierProvider<QuizModel>(
              create: (context) => QuizModel(snapshot.data),
              child: Scaffold(
                //appBar: AppBar(title: Text("nice app")),
                body: Consumer<QuizModel>(builder: (context, QuizModel, child) {
                  if (QuizModel.questions.length == 0) {
                    return Center(
                      child: Text("Loading..."),
                    );
                  } else {
                    print(snapshot.data);
                    // return Text("Ok");
                    return QuizModel.qindex < QuizModel.questions.length
                        ? ViewQuiz(QuizModel.questions, QuizModel.qindex)
                        : ViewResult(QuizModel.score);
                  }
                }),
              ),
            );
```

answer.dart

```
class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final qzm = Provider.of<QuizModel>(context, listen: false);

    //var ptions = widget.options;
    return Column(
      children: (qzm.questions[qzm.qindex]["qoptions"] as List<dynamic>)
          .map((opt) => AnswerOption(qzm, opt))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
}

class AnswerOption extends StatefulWidget {
  var qzm;
  var opt;
  AnswerOption(this.qzm, this.opt);
  
  @override
  _AnswerOptionState createState() => _AnswerOptionState();
}

var colordata = Colors.white;

class _AnswerOptionState extends State<AnswerOption> {
  _checker(ans) {
    // print(idx);
    if (widget.qzm.questions[widget.qzm.qindex]["answer"] == ans) {
      print("nice");
      setState(() {
        colordata = Colors.green;
      });

      Timer(
          Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          () => {
                setState(() {
                  colordata = Colors.white;
                }),
                widget.qzm.check(true),
              });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        colordata = Colors.red;
      });
      Timer(
          Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
          () => {
                setState(() {
                  colordata = Colors.white;
                }),
                widget.qzm.check(false),
              });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 250,
      child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () => _checker(widget.opt),
          child: Text(
            widget.opt,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.black),
          ),
          color: colordata
          // duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

full code :

https://github.com/ishworgiri1999/quizel/tree/main/lib

Answer (score 1):

Stateful widget cannot update itself until programmer specify where and when it must be updated calling the `seState` method.

Parent widget rebuilds child widget only if child widget is in subtree of parent widget which is updated.

Widgets can be updated completely using `setState` or partially, using `Provider`/`Consumer` or `ValueListenableBuilder`.

Comment: I have updated the question . Can you look once again

Comment: Do not use `var` for class members, use data types because it confuses. Using timer here is bad idea. Use method `didUpdateWidget` (override it) to check if question if changed, i.e. `if (oldWidget.qzm != widget.qzm) { // update color to blue}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with state management, I would use the provider package. Otherwise if it's a smaller app in which you don't have global state (state shared between multiple widgets) you can call `setState` if the UI should be rebuilt. The UI will only update if the state used by the child widget is changed.

Please provide a short code snippet to reproduce your situation.